# React function called multiple time

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to understand why my function is called 5 times.
The function return nothing the first 3 times and then twice with the data. I would like it to run only only once, when the data are ready.

Parent component:

```
export default function PublicCircles() {

  const [circles, getCircles] = useState('');
  const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

  useEffect(() => {
    getPublicCircles();
  }, []);

  const getPublicCircles = () => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'fr',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
     axios.get('https://myurl.com/api/get-public-circles?lang=All', { headers })
      .then((response) => {
          const publicCircles = response.data.data;
          getCircles(publicCircles);
        }) 
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
  };

  return (
      <PublicCircle circles={circles} />
  )
}
```

Child component:

```
export default function PublicCircle(props) {
  console.log(props.circles)
  return(
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

Result:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please checkout this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110785/axios-post-sent-request-twice/71110880#71110880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like it to run only only once, when the data are ready.

So you don't want the `<PublicCircle>` component to be rendered at all until the prop you're sending it has data?  In that case you should conditionally render it.  Currently you're always rendering it:

```
return (
  <PublicCircle circles={circles} />
);
```

But you can simply introduce a condition in there.  Your default value of `circles` is an empty string:

```
const [circles, getCircles] = useState('');
```

So check for that in the condition.  For example:

```
return (
  circles === '' ? null :
  <PublicCircle circles={circles} />
);
```

Then the `PublicCircles` component will render nothing (`null`) by default, and render a `<PublicCircle>` element when `circles` contains data.

Note that your component *may still re-render* for any number of reasons.  Any state change here or anywhere up the hierarchy can trigger a re-render.

Comment: In my case, I explicitly compare the previous value with new value to set variable. By doing this, it'll not trigger the rendering of element or method call, unless the variable has actually changed.